# Is there another alternate way to add Console.WriteLine() in this scenario

Tags: c#, instance, utf-16, console.writeline

In this code, I wish to add a Console.Writeline() after each Console.ReadLine() but how I am implementing the code it is giving me an error. Is there another way how I can add Console.WriteLine() in the instance?

```
     public void CreateAccount()
        {
        Console.WriteLine("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");
        Console.WriteLine("Create an Account");
        Client createAccount = new Client("Create")
        {
            NameOfUser = Console.ReadLine(),
            SurnameOfUser = Console.ReadLine(),
            UserID = Console.ReadLine(),
            UserEmail = Console.ReadLine(),
            UserHomeAdd = Console.ReadLine(),
            UserMobileNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()),
            UsernameField = Console.ReadLine(),
            PasswordField = Console.ReadLine(),
            CoffePoints = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())

        };


        List<Client> accountData = new List<Client>()
        {
            createAccount
        };
```

Comment: what error? Please post as much information as possible. Maybe we can just fix the error

Comment: If I add a Console.WriteLine() between each Console.ReadLine() it gives me the **represent text as a sequence of utf-16 code units** Error

Comment: Do not use `int.Parse` on user input. I'll get a vexing exception if the user enters a string that can't be parsed to an int, like `André`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put WriteLine() between your ReadLine(), because you're initializing properties of your new Client. You can, however, do it like this instead:

```
public void CreateAccount()
{
    Console.WriteLine("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");
    Console.WriteLine("Create an Account");
    Client createAccount = new Client("Create");

    Console.WriteLine("Enter NameOfUser ");
    createAccount.NameOfUser = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter SurnameOfUser ");
    createAccount.SurnameOfUser = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter UserID ");
    createAccount.UserID = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter UserEmail ");
    createAccount.UserEmail = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter UserHomeAdd ");
    createAccount.UserHomeAdd = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter UserMobileNumber ");
    createAccount.UserMobileNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter UsernameField ");
    createAccount.UsernameField = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter PasswordField ");
    createAccount.PasswordField = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter CoffePoints ");
    createAccount.CoffePoints = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


    List<Client> accountData = new List<Client>()
    {
        createAccount
    };
```

When you appreciate why this works, I'd recommend to do like Isma suggested (if you've been taught about how to make your own methods yet), to make your code cleaner. I wrote this to help you appreciate why what you wrote wasn't working out. Shorthand property initializers like this:

```
Something s = new Something(){
   Property1 = ReadLine(),  //no semicolon here, this is all
   Property2 = ReadLine()   //one line of code in a=1,b=2,c=3 pattern
};
```

Cannot have multiple lines of code like this:

```
Something s = new Something(){
   Property1 = WriteLine("Blah"); ReadLine(); //can't put a semicolon here
   Property2 = WriteLine("Blah"); ReadLine(); //it HAS to be a comma, because it
   Property3 = WriteLine("Blah"); ReadLine(); //HAS to be a single line of code
};
```

Remember that it is not the return key that defines a new line of code in C#, it's the semicolon. It's simply a language rule that the pattern for setting properties like this is single line, and only one statement can appear on the right hand side of the `=`

You must either not use the shorthand way (as above) or you must put all the multiple lines of code you want to use into a single method, and then call that method (as Isma suggested)

I'd also like to point out that you said you wanted to "writeline a message after every readline" - note that your program will wait for the user to input anything before it prints your message. Isma's way (and this above) print a message BEFORE asking for a readline, because this is more typically what you'd want to do.

If you really do want it after, then move them to be after (but I guess really you can only be thanking them for their input, and overly thankful things are annoying...) so something like this (Isma's way):

```
private static string ReadLine(string writeMessage)
{
    string s = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(writeMessage);
    return s;
}
```

or my way:

```
public void CreateAccount()
{
    Console.WriteLine("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");
    Console.WriteLine("Create an Account");
    Client createAccount = new Client("Create");

    createAccount.NameOfUser = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Thanks for entering NameOfUser..");
```

Comment: @AndréColeiro no probs. I added some more detail to help your learning

Comment: Thanks @Caius Jard really helpfull :)

Answer (score 4):

You could create a method that prints something and returns Console.ReadLine(), for example:

```
private static string ReadLine(string writeMessage, bool parseAsInt = false)
{
    Console.WriteLine(writeMessage);

    var line = Console.ReadLine();

    if (parseAsInt)
    {
        int parseInt = 0;
        int.TryParse(line, out parseInt);
        line = parseInt.ToString();
    }

    return line;
}
```

Then just call it when creating the object:

```
Client createAccount = new Client("Create")
{
    NameOfUser = ReadLine("What's your name?"),
    SurnameOfUser = ReadLine("Input your surname"),
    [...]
    CoffePoints = ReadLine("Coffe points?", true)
};
```